# Send data from Apache Flume to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, flume, elastic-stack

I am using the following flume 1.7 agent configuration to stream data from a Kafka 0.9.0.1 topic, and to send data to ElasticSearch which is setup on Rancher using the ES found in catalog which is version v0.5.0.

```
agent.sources  = flume_test
agent.channels = kafka_test_channel
agent.sinks =   ElasticSearchSink

agent.sources.flume_test.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
agent.sources.flume_test.zookeeperConnect = stage-kafka01.stage:2181,stage-kafka02.stage:2181,stage-kafka03.stage:2181
agent.sources.flume_test.topic = hrzn_stage1_test
agent.sources.flume_test.groupId = flume_kafka_stage1_test
agent.sources.flume_test.channels = kafka_test_channel
agent.sources.flume_test.spoolDir = /var/log/spoolDir/auth
agent.sources.flume_test.interceptors = i1
agent.sources.flume_test.interceptors.i1.type = com.cpm.interceptors.TestInterceptor$Builder

agent.channels.kafka_test_channel.type = file
agent.channels.kafka_test_channel.checkpointDir =  /dev/shm/flume/checkpointsDir/auth
agent.channels.kafka_test_channel.dataDirs = /dev/shm/flume/dataDir/auth
agent.channels.kafka_test_channel.checkpointInterval = 10
agent.channels.kafka_test_channel.capacity = 10000
agent.channels.kafka_test_channel.transactionCapacity = 1000

agent.sinks.ElasticSearchSink.type = elasticsearch
agent.sinks.ElasticSearchSink.hostNames = 10.42.242.78:9300
agent.sinks.ElasticSearchSink.indexName = auth
agent.sinks.ElasticSearchSink.indexType = logs
agent.sinks.ElasticSearchSink.clusterName = elasticsearch
agent.sinks.ElasticSearchSink.batchSize = 500
agent.sinks.ElasticSearchSink.ttl = 5d
agent.sinks.ElasticSearchSink.serializer = org.apache.flume.sink.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchDynamicSerializer 
agent.sinks.ElasticSearchSink.channel = kafka_test_channel
```

10.42.242.78 is one of the publishing addresses which I have extracted from the logs, i.e.

```
publish_address {10.42.242.78:9300}, bound_addresses {10.42.242.78:9300}, {172.17.0.5:9300}
```

On top of ES, I am using elasticsearch-kopf, and I have created an index having the following setup

```
{
  "number_of_shards": "1",
  "number_of_replicas": "1",
  "mappings": {
    "default": {
      "properties": {
        "uuid": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "brandId": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "creationDate": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Flume connects to the publishing endpoints, but I am not able to see data in ES, at all. I am also trying to search using the index, but nothing comes up.

An example of a message sent from Flume can be

```
{"uuid":"12345","brandId":"12345","creationDate":"2017-09-13T20:32:15.660","payload":"test"}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What Flume's logs say? Are you able to see the reception of events at the source?

Comment: I am getting org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available, however I am sure I cannot connect to the elastic search. I am now not on rancher, but I installed an ELK stack from here https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk#configuration